# Unknown programming error?

Tags: python

I have tried over and over again in order to get my code to work, but it just hasn't.

```
ename = "Blue Slime"
ehp = 5
edf = 0
eatk = 1
print ("A % has appeared!") % ('ename')
print ("Enemy Stats:")
print ("HP = %") % ('ehp')
print ("DF = %") % ('edf')
print ("ATK = %") % ('eatk')
```

When I run it, the program says

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 'a' (0x61) at index 5
```

I can't figure out what the issue is, and I would like some help with what I should change.

Comment: The error message included line information. Please include it.

Comment: You don't need the parens around your strings and you need `%s` not just %

Comment: That's the fifth line in the code, "print ("A % has appeared!") % ('ename')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

("A % has appeared!") % ('ename')
should be

print("A %s has appeared!" % 'ename')

Answer (score 1):

```
("A % has appeared!") % ('ename')
```

should be

```
("A %s has appeared!") % ('ename')
```

i.e. you need a format specifier `s` after `%`. Read up on string formatting again.

Comment: Right as I saw this, I remembered it. I've made stuff like this before, thanks :)